# Как удалить из словаря ключ и значение по указанному ключу?

Tags: python, словари

Есть словарь.

```
shelf = {
 '1': ['3'],
 '2': []
}
```

Ввожу номер строки, которую хочу удалить, например, 2. Если в ней значение пустое то удаляю.

Понимаю как циклом пройтись по всем ключам и удалить с пустыми значениями, а с этим примером завис.

```
dic = {key: value for key, value in shelf.items() if value != []}
```

Так сделал по всем строкам. Хочу понять как это делать по конкретному ключу введенному в input.

Comment: `shelf.pop('2')` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так:

```
n = input()
if n in shelf and not shelf[n]:
    del shelf[n]
```

1. `n in shelf` - проверяем, что ключ есть в словаре
2. `not shelf[n]` - проверяем, что значение по этому ключу - пустой список
3. `del shelf[n]` - удаляем из словаря пару ключ/значение по ключу