# Как удалить ключ и его значение из словаря?

Tags: python, словари, dict

Суть такая,  я могу добавлять в словарь много ключей и значений, но если такой ключ и такое значение уже есть в словаре, мне нужно их удалять.

Kак такое можно сделать?

Comment: `d = {"a":1, "b":2}; _ = d.pop("a"); print(d)` ;)

Comment: `del d['a']` ещё, ну основы же, блин

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как удалить из словаря ключ и значение по указанному ключу?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1174914/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87-%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d1%83)

Answer (score 5):

Безопасный способ удаления ключа и значения - даже если такой ключ отсутствует , не будет исключительной ситуации (`exception`):

```
_ = dict_.pop(key, None)
```

Пример:

```
d = dict(a=1, b=2, c=3)
print(d)
_ = d.pop("b")
print(d)
_ = d.pop("blah", None)
print(d)
```

Вывод:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
{'a': 1, 'c': 3}
{'a': 1, 'c': 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов есть несколько. Про `pop` уже написали. Но традиционный всё-таки вариант через `del`. Приведу варианты с проверкой наличия ключа и значения:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
if 'a' in d and d['a'] == 1:
    del d['a']
```

Или:

```
if d.get('a') == 1:
    del d['a']
```

Comment: Но мне нужно делать проверку на ключ и значение одновременно, может быть много одинаковых ключей но при этом разные значение, а я при добавлении проверяю, если такой ключ с таким значение уже есть, то он удаляется

Comment: @Filips_1400 много одинаковых ключей не может быть)

Comment: Может) когда словарь включает подсловари. К примеру, собранные по id.

Comment: @Filips_1400 Ок, сделал проверку и ключа и значения. Вариант один ключ - много значений возможен только если вы значения храните в какой-то коллекции. Покажите ваш словарь тогда.

Comment: @AndyPavlov Если значение это коллекция и имеется в виду проверка значения внутри этой коллекции, тогда понятно )